# fixing Module Not found Error when importing openpyxl in .py file?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to use openpyxl with python 3.7, but when starting my .py file in my windows shell I got the ModuleNotFoundError.

It is kinda weird as i don't get this error if I write my code in the python interpreter (can create and save .xlsx files)

I tried uninstalling and installing again via pip3 and/or running shell as admin (pip is updated).
I don't use many other modules (os, wx, csv and calendar) so it shouldn't interfere.
I renamed my .py file so i'm sure there is no name conflict.

```py
import openpyxl
#from openpyxl import Workbook (doesn't work either)
```

Do you have an idea where this may coming from ?

regards,

Clem

Comment: Do you have multiple Python versions installed?

Comment: Nope, only 3.7
However I just found a solution, looks to be working at the moment. I will answer my question for others people who might need it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution, as I don't get the error anymore.

I added the encoding and language interpreter at the beginning of my .py file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openpyxl import Workbook
```

Hope it helps :)