# ModuleNotFoundError, even though module is successfully installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm trying to run a scrip that uses openpyxl.  I have the module installed correctly and am *only*
 getting this error when trying to run the script by clicking the file/ running it from the command line.  It *does* work when I run it from the command line as "python enter-info.py", but not when I run it by itself.

Error when trying to run script

[image]

Comment: That suggests you may have a different version of Python associated with file type `.py` or that you have a *shebang* on the first line pointing to a different version of Python.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a `.py` file as a stand alone, you should use the [`shebang`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take) line.
Also, you should use the compatible `python` version

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple versions of Python installed on your system? It may be running with a different version of Python when you run it that way. For a quick fix, try running `pip install openpyxl` or `pip3 install openpyxl --user`.

In times of desperation, the above have worked for me; however, I recommend using a [virtual environment](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) in cases like these to prevent this issue in the future. Otherwise, [this solution looks promising as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57417678/11986500) although I have never tried it myself.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
python3 yourfile.py  # for python3 if you have python2 installed
python yourfile.py # if you have only one python installed
```

Comment: This works, but it's not the problem.  I'm trying to run the script from the icon, but that's when it throws the error.  Running python <file>.py works, running just <file>.py does not.

Comment: What OS do you use?